# Адресная строка.

Tags: html, браузер

Чем отличаются ссылки типа http://vk.com/typical_proger от http://vk.com/typical_proger.php, как они создаются(неужто root/typical_proger/index.php, это же из баз данных берётся) и какой в них смысл?
Можете ответить ссылкой на статью, если таковые есть.
Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется [ЧПУ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%9F%D0%A3_(%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)). Обычно делают с помощью модуля, который входит в состав Апача. Он получает все входящие url, фильтрует их с помощью регулярных выражений и вызывает привязанный к ним скрипт. А как скрипты будут на сервере - это уже дело программиста. Гугл по словам apache ЧПУ выдаст много информации.

Другой вариант - cgi. Так как в линуксе (на базе чего обычно сервера работают), расширение играет в основном информационную роль, то файлы могут иметь различные расширения (в том числе и отсутствие такового).  А как запускать - система определяет по первым байтам файла.

Comment: А в чём смысл этого? Адрес красивее смотрится?

Comment: классический пример. что красивее и понятнее для человека выглядит

    http://example.com/news.php?year=2000&month=1&day=1

или

    http://example.com/news/2000/1/1

Также есть мнение, что поисковики более правильно индексируют подобное (но это больше похоже на "городские легенды").

Comment: @Dazar конечно красиво. И тем более понятно, вот пример:

что лучше?

> site.ru/archive/2012-10-20/

или: 

> site.ru/archive.php?date=2012-10-20

Comment: Спасибо) уже переделываю свой проект)  
все относительные ссылки полетели, но работает)

Comment: Я правильно понял принцип работы RewriteRule: если URL подходит под шаблон, то преобразуется по правилу, а если нет, то ничего не происходит, так?

Comment: то идет к следующему правилу. Нет больше правил - пытается использовать урл. Хотя реализаций подобных вещей много, и, возможно, некоторые и пропускают плохие урлы.